# Simple Apache ProxyPass equivalent in WSO2ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

This is my proxy.

```
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="lascaux"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
 <target>
     <inSequence>
         <header name="To"
             expression="concat('http://10.0.0.2:8080/',syn:get-property('To'))"/>
         <send/>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence>
        <send/>
     </outSequence>
 </target>
 <description/>
</proxy>
```

and it should contact a REST webapp server which will return 200/404/409..etc based on the operation. i am finding hard to make the PUT request work with it. GET is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an API rather than a proxy service. Please find the example in the link below

https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Getting+Started+with+REST+APIs

Comment: thanks nadeesha..i gone through it but our service is large so adding every entry is not needed for now.. i fixed it by referring an example in this link https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service#UsingRESTwithaProxyService-RESTClientandRESTService